# XSLT importing a partial XML segment into XML with processing-instructions

Tags: xml, xslt, document, processing-instruction

I have a xml document that I need to replace specific nodes with partial xml segments that contains both nodes as well as processing-instructions.  I want to preserve the PI's but am running into issues in the replacement.

Segment example: general.xml

```
<root>
  <!--General Settings -->
  <?mapping EnvironmentSetting="envname"?>
  <setting name="SubscriptionName" value="*" />
</root>
```

Source xml:

```
<environment>
  <General />
</environment>
```

Transform -

```
<xsl:template match="* | processing-instruction() | comment()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*/General">
  <xsl:copy-of select="document('general.xml')/root"/>
</xsl:template>
```

The output is:

```
<environment>
  <root>
    <!--General Settings -->
    <?mapping EnvironmentSetting="envname"?>
    <setting name="SubscriptionName" value="*" />
  </root>
</environment>
```

But I want:

```
<environment>
  <!--General Settings -->
  <?mapping EnvironmentSetting="envname"?>
  <setting name="SubscriptionName" value="*" />
</environment>
```

Changing the document section to root/* drops processing-instructions (and comments)

```
<xsl:copy-of select="document('general.xml')/root/*"/>
...
<environment>
  <setting name="SubscriptionName" value="*" />
</environment>
```

Changing the document section to root/process-instructions drops the nodes

```
<xsl:copy-of select="document('general.xml')/root/processing-instruction()"/>
...
<environment>
  <?mapping EnvironmentSetting="envname"?>
</environment>
```

Trying to do an | just matches first parameter -

```
<xsl:copy-of select="document('general.xml')/root/processing-instruction() | * | comment()"/>
...
<environment>
  <?mapping EnvironmentSetting="envname"?>
</environment>
```

So how do I get my cake and eat it too?  I seem so close, but am having problems finding any examples of doing what I want to do.

Comment: Your modified identity template is rather odd. It's more useful to start with an actual identity template and add empty templates for types of nodes you *don't* want to copy, e.g. `<xsl:template match="text()[normalize-space() = '']` />.

Comment: Not sure I understood your comment, which portion your you referring to as identity template?  I'm fairly new to XSLT, so please forgive my ignorance if that seems like I'm asking a dumb question.

Comment: I refer to the first `<xs:template>` in your question. The identity transform (a.k.a. identity template) is one of the true basics in XSLT. You will find tons of reading material by those keywords alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<xsl:template match="* | processing-instruction() | comment()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*/General">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="document('general.xml')/root"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Alternatively you could make a copy of several types of nodes using the union operator:

```
<xsl:template match="*/General">
  <xsl:variable name="r" select="document('general.xml')/root" />
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$r/* | $r/processing-instruction() | $r/comment()" />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: First example is exactly what I needed.  I actually have multiple document snippets and depending on what I want as output xml, I need to grab one or many of these snippets.

I'll look more into your 2nd example of a way to extend what I'm doing.  Haven't used variables yet.

Comment: BTW: It would make sense to define variables you need more than once at the top level instead of inside individual templates.